# default name server behavior (named.conf configuration; Bind9)

Tags: bind, httpd, nameserver

Is it possible to configure named.conf to have a default behavior?

For instance, if this is my `named.conf` ( `https://gist.github.com/3c755018696e262ee4d9` ) & this is `guubo.com.db` ( `https://gist.github.com/affa63b5a5b250b5de17` )

Basically there are many domains pointing to `ns1.hotelpublisher.com ns2, ..` and they all have the same configuration as `guubo.com.db` (except for the domain name, of course). But Google settings, server support email, etc. is same on every domain.

Comment: Why don't you just write script for auto-generation of default configs?

Comment: Yes, this is the thing I am working on at the moment. Though, I find it kinda redundant if the same thing is possible without all that mess.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what I did was: I've created `default.db` file which I've included with every master zone. `named.conf` therefore looks like this:

```
# [..]
zone "hotelpublisher.com"
{
    type master;
    file "/var/named/default.db";
};

zone "guubo.com"
{
    type master;
    file "/var/named/default.db";
};
```

And `default.db` like this:

```
$ttl 14400
@ IN SOA ns1.hotelpublisher.com. server@hotelpublisher.com. (
 2011041105; Serial in YYYYMMDDXX (XX is increment)
 10800; refresh seconds
 3600; retry
 604800; expire
 38400; minimum
);

@ IN A 77.79.10.25
@ IN NS ns1.hotelpublisher.com.
@ IN NS ns2.hotelpublisher.com.

@ IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 5 alt2.aspml.l.google.com.
@ IN MX 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
@ IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.

www IN CNAME @
mail IN CNAME ghs.google.com.

@ TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr mx:aspmx.googlemail.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all"
```

This removed a lot of redundancy. If any comments, feel free to share.

Comment: Use in-bailiwick intermediate names for your content DNS servers.  i.e. use `ns1` (not fully qualified, note) rather than the fully qualified `ns1.hotelpublisher.com.`.  And add `ns1 IN A 77.79.10.25` and `ns2 IN A 77.79.13.238` of course.